# Debian & Ubuntu different time fromat

Tags: date, ubuntu, debian

I have two Jenkins agents, one with OS Ubuntu 22.04 server and one with Debian server.

On Ubuntu my format is:

```
Tue Feb 21 09:22:05 PM CET 2023
```

On Debian it is:

```
Tue 21 Feb 2023 09:21:45 PM CET
```

This will follow up in Cypress logs with:
Ubuntu:

```
March 25, 2022 at 10:16 AM GMT+1
```

Debian:

```
March 25, 2022, 10:16 AM GMT+1
```

Is there a way to become the same time format on Ubuntu as it is on Debian?

Answer (score -1):

date +'%B %d, %Y, %I:%M %p GMT%-:::z'

February 21, 2023, 10:14 PM GMT+1

Comment: This answer seems to contain some code for time format. Where should it be placed? Is it in the Jenkins settings somewhere?